# window.showModalDialog open new window on button click

Tags: javascript

I created a pop-up window using the javascript `window.showModalDialog`, and that page has a button but the problem is when I click that button it opens a new window, it's the same page of my pop-up window.

I search on internet and find a solution but the solution is not working

```
<head>
    <base target="_self" />
</head>
```

I am opening the window using

```
window.showModalDialog(url, '', 'unadorned:yes;resizable:1;dialogHeight:550px;dialogwidth:985px;scroll:yes;status=yes,scrollbars:yes,resizable:yes,location:yes');
```

and page contain a button, on the click of the button it perform some action in controller and after performing action it execute code

```
  requestDetails.MessageText = "Request has been saved successfully.";

  if (requestDetails.isCloneRequest)
      return Content("<script> alert('" + requestDetails.MessageText + "');  window.close();  </script>");
  else
      return Content("<script> alert('" + requestDetails.MessageText + "'); var url = ''; var currentUrl  = location.href;  currentUrl = currentUrl.toLowerCase(); window.location.href = currentUrl+'" + url + "' ;  </script>");
```

that open another window with above URL. I want to open that URL in same `showModalDialog`. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: if possible can u add the same in jsfiddle ,it would be easier to understand your problem and rectify it faster.

Comment: I am opening the window using :"  window.showModalDialog(url, '', 'unadorned:yes;resizable:1;dialogHeight:550px;dialogwidth:985px;scroll:yes;status=no,scrollbars:yes,resizable:yes');  "   and page contain a button , on the click of the button it perform some action in controller and after performing action it return a new view with model in another window instead of the same widow.  I want to stop that behavior

Comment: user1194147:dont use code directly in comments .better add them in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: `target` for `<base>` elements = "A name or keyword indicating the default location to display the result when hyperlinks or forms cause navigation, for elements that do not have an explicit target reference." ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base )

Comment: any solution will be appreciated..